# MATLAB - Component of array and matrix multiplication

Tags: matlab, matrix-multiplication

I create a 1x7 array with vector component (so the actual size is 1x7x3) by this code:

```
[half_phi half_theta] = meshgrid(-90:30:90, 0);
[half_x half_y half_z] = sph2cart(degtorad(half_phi), degtorad(half_theta), 1);
halfDir = cat(3, half_x, half_y, half_z)
```

What i want to do next is to make a 3x3 matrix multiply with each vector and finally return also a 1x7x3 array, how to achieve this concisely ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want?

```
A=rand(1,7,3);
B=rand(3,3);

C=reshape(reshape(A,1*7,3)*B,[1,7,3]);
```

or maybe

```
C=reshape(reshape(A,1*7,3)*B',[1,7,3]); %%% with B' instead of B
```

Comment: The second `reshape` isn't necessarily needed. Assuming `C` isn't already allocated, you can do: `C(1,:,:)=reshape(A,1*7,3)*B;`